# Solved - Cannot install python3.7-venv in (X)Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: python3

I just updated my XUbuntu 18.04 installation to 18.10 (note: for some reason I stopped `do-release-upgrade` while the packages were still downloading, then I continued it `apt upgrade` + reboot, everything seems fine).
I installed python3.7 via package manager and tried to make it the default:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
# This may not be needed for only 1 alternative, but does not hurt to run it:
sudo update-alternatives --config python
```

This is the problem:

```
$ sudo apt install python3.7-venv 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.7-venv : Depends: python3.7 (= 3.7.1-1~18.10) but 3.7.1-1+bionic1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Why does it try to use bionic and how to fix it?

My system is fully updated, just ran `apt update`, and `apt upgrade` says: `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

My /etc/apt/source.list (note I manually deleted the commented out bionic lines to clean it up):

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic universe
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic multiverse
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://hu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu cosmic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security multiverse
# deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu cosmic stable # disabled on upgrade to cosmic
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

Note: I also tried to use another mirror, then `sudo apt update` but the error remained the same.

Comment: Please, post the output of `sudo apt install python3.7`.

Comment: @Olimjon Thanks, it helped me to solve the problem! :) The output contained `python3.7 is already the newest version (3.7.1-1+bionic1).` So I did `sudo apt remove python3.7` then `sudo apt autoremove` (to remove the dependencies which were also from bionic), then `sudo apt install python3.7` and it made it cosmic! :) So then `sudo apt install python3.7-venv` succeeded finally.